# C# lambda query using generic type

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have three classes, they all have a property Date. I would like to write a generic class to return all the records for one date.
Now the problem is: how can I write the lambda expression using generic type T?

The code simple is as below (i'll not compile, because "r.Date" would not working,but it's the effect that I'd like to achive)

```
Class GenericService<T>: IGenericService<T> where T:class
{
      ...
      readonly IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepository;
      public IEnumerable<T> GetRecordList(DateTime date)
      {
             var query=_genericRepository.FindBy(r=>r.Date=date);
}
```

Thank you for you help!

Regards,
Léona

Comment: Do they all have `Date` property on a common interface? If not, is that something you can add?

Comment: If there is no possibility for a common interfaceyou can use reflection

Comment: May be implement some interface and use it?

Comment: Except if you have complex algorithm to run on multiple tables, you might make your code too complex for no benefit.

Given how generics works in C#, either use a common interface or Action<> and Func<>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option is to build an `Expression` dynamically. This can be useful if you don't want to or can't add an `IDate` interface to the model objects, and if `FindBy` needs an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` (for example, it translates to `IQueryable<T>.Where(...)` internally for EntityFramework or similar.

Like @JonB's answer, this has no compile-time safety to ensure that `T` has a `Date` property or field. It will only fail at runtime.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetRecordList(DateTime date)
{
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "object");
    var propertyOrFieldExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, "Date");
    var equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyOrFieldExpression, Expression.Constant(date, typeof(DateTime)));
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalityExpression, parameterExpression);

    var query = _genericRepository.FindBy(lambdaExpression);
    return query;
}
```

Comment: It's a better solution cause implementing IDate requires maintenance afterwards if more entities added.

Comment: In my scenario, the lambda query is going to be converted into a DB query, and it's unknown in coding phase that which properties of T are needed. This solution works for me. Brilliant!

Answer (score 14):

Write an interface which has `IDate` and all of your entities must implement `IDate` and write `GenericService` like this :

```
public class GenericService<T>: IGenericService<T> where T : class, IDate
{
    readonly IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepository;
    public IEnumerable<T> GetRecordList(DateTime date)
    {
         var query=_genericRepository.FindBy(r => r.Date = date);
    }
}

public interface IDate
{
    DateTime Date{ set; get; }
}

public class Entity : IDate
{
    DateTime Date { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you put a bounty? You don't like your own (upvoted and accepted) answer? What really are you expecting?

Comment: @IvanStoev the reason is simple as I set in my bounty `This question has not received enough attention.` and also I wanted to see other solution which what romain-aga also answered is interesting to me. and the final reason is I wanted to developers see this solution and consider using interface like this for generic useage

Comment: You'll probably want a second equals sign in that `FindBy` method call (unlike the OP).  Either that or `FindBy` takes a `Func<T, DateTime>` and the func passed in will overwrite all date classes' Date property with the date searched for!

Answer (score 7):

Another solution if you can't implement an interface and don't want to use the reflection, could be to pass how to get the date to the GenericService:

### By a property:

```
public class GenericService<T>: IGenericService<T> where T : class
{
    public Func<T, DateTime> DateGetter { get; set; }

    readonly IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepository;
    public IEnumerable<T> GetRecordList(DateTime date)
    {
        var query=_genericRepository.FindBy(r => DateGetter(r) == date);
    }
}
```

### By the constructor:

```
public class GenericService<T>: IGenericService<T> where T : class
{
    Func<T, DateTime> _dateGetter;

    public GenericService(..., Func<T, DateTime> dateGetter)
    {
        _dateGetter = dateGetter
        ...
    }

    readonly IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepository;
    public IEnumerable<T> GetRecordList(DateTime date)
    {
        var query=_genericRepository.FindBy(r => _dateGetter(r) == date);
    }
}
```

### By the method itself:

```
public class GenericService<T>: IGenericService<T> where T : class
{
    readonly IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepository;
    public IEnumerable<T> GetRecordList(DateTime date, Func<T, DateTime> dateGetter)
    {
        var query=_genericRepository.FindBy(r => dateGetter(r) == date);
    }
}
```

### By type:

The Adam Ralph' solution inspired me this one (not the best I guess, but it still work)

```
public class GenericService<T>: IGenericService<T> where T : class
{
    public Dictionary<Type, Func<object, DateTime>> _dateGetter = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, DateTime>>()
    {
        { typeof(TypeWithDate), x => ((TypeWithDate)x).Date },
        { typeof(TypeWithDate2), x => ((TypeWithDate2)x).Date }
    };

    readonly IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepository;
    public IEnumerable<T> GetRecordList(DateTime date)
    {
        var query=_genericRepository.FindBy(r => _dateGetter[typeof(T)](r) = date);
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for this solution. In fact, i could use in interface, but in fact, for the maintenance, it's better if I don't use it.
I noticed in your solution, you also implemented IDate... I believe that is a mistake, isn't it? If yes, better to correct it...
Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes it is a mistake, I copied pasted the code from the Arvin answer ^^"

Comment: thanks @romain-aga your solution is also a good way for this issue, but in this case if we are using EntityFramework we need LINQ to Entitie and I believe bu runnig this code this error will occur : `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities`. but again this is a valid solution if we are not using EntityFramework

Comment: I will have to make a test to check what you are saying. But I think if LINQ is an issue, you can still change all the LINQ queries by something more traditional (even if it's heavier to deal without it).

Comment: Aren't we missing another `=` in this: `.FindBy(r => dateGetter(r) = date);`?

Comment: Yup, there is one missing. It should be fine now ;)

Comment: I've also tested this solution. Indeed, this error will occur: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. And it's not easy to deal with it.

Comment: Which version of entities do you use ? I would like to test in the same conditions as you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the list of objects isn't enormous, writing something generic for 3 classes could be over engineering. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

```
objects.Where(obj =>
    (obj as Foo)?.DateTime == date ||
    (obj as Bar)?.DateTime == date ||
    (obj as Baz)?.DateTime == date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your `FindBy` method is structured or what it returns, but you might be able to use the `dynamic` keyword like this:

```
   var query=_genericRepository.FindBy(r=>((dynamic)r).Date==date);
```

If the `FindBy` method is returning an `IEnumerable<T>`, then you might have to add a `.Cast<T>()` to the return statement otherwise you might get a type of `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

This is by no means typesafe and you can get runtime errors if `T` doesn't have a `Date` property. But it's one option to consider.

Comment: Hello @JonB, Thanks for your answer. 
1/ The FindBy method return an IQueryable<T>. 
2/ Your code get a compile error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.